# no internet in terminal ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, internet, 16.10

root@ORION:~# sudo apt-get install netcat-openbsd tcpdump traceroute mtr

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
netcat-openbsd is already the newest version (1.105-7ubuntu1).
tcpdump is already the newest version (4.7.4-1ubuntu1.16.10.1).
tcpdump set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-4.8.0-22 linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic linux-signed-image-4.8.0-22-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mtr-tiny
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mtr traceroute
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
Need to get 102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 202 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 traceroute amd64 1:2.1.0-2
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 mtr amd64 0.86-1ubuntu1
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.1.0-2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mtr/mtr_0.86-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

root@ORION:~# apt-get update --fix-missing

```
Err:1 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                       
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                                  
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease                                         
Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb stable InRelease             
Could not resolve 'dl.bintray.com'
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/conscioususer/polly-daily/ubuntu yakkety    InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conscioususer/polly-daily/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.bintray.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

no internet access in terminal of ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: It looks like your DNS is not working. In `terminal`, show me the output of `host www.buy.com` and `host 8.8.8.8` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Edit your question to include this output. Have you set up special DNS servers in your network configuration?

Comment: it was working fine just before. and i have net everywhere else like chrome firefox etc

Comment: Do you see all of the "Could not resolve" error messages? Sounds like a DNS problem. If you'd like for me to dig further, please supply the information I requested earlier. `ping www.buy.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrade 16.04 to 16.10. All commands OTHER THAN nslookup / host and something based on dns query cannot resolve any domain name. It's really a funny bug. Nslookup / host / dig / ping returns nothing wrong. There is nothing wrong in resolv.conf either. My workaround is install a squid on the same server and set http_proxy to this squid instance.